# Wp List Table - wpdb results are not displaying

Tags: plugins, wp-list-table

I am a newbie i wordpress dev. So i wanna display a results, taken from custom wordpress database table. So I have written this:

```
    if( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}
class Q_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( array(
            'singular' => 'test',
            'plural' => 'tests',
            'ajax' => false
        ));
        $this->prepare_items();
        $this->display();
    }

    function get_columns() {
        $columns = array(
            'id'    => 'ID',
            'subject'     => 'Title',
            'name'   => 'Username',
            'date'   => 'Posted on'
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
        switch( $column_name ) {
            case 'id':
            case 'subject':
            case 'name':
            case 'date':
                return $item[ $column_name ];
            default:
                return print_r( $item, true ) ;
        }
    }

    function prepare_items() {

        global $wpdb;

        $sql = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}fenq_questions"));
        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();
        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);


        var_dump($sql);


        $this->items = $sql;
    }
}


class FenQuestingAdmin{



    function display(){
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //admin all questions template
        ?>

        <div class="wrap">

         <h2><?php _e('FenQuesting Settings','fenquesting-slug'); ?></h2>

        <?php 
           new Q_List_Table();
        ?>

        </div>        
        <?php
    }

}
```

The display function from FenQuestingAdmin class is linked to the main file and set as a function for admin page...

So this code gives this result:

[image: Results]

When I am using an example array, constructed by me, I am getting 0 problems, but the main aim is to display the array, taken from db.

Thanx for your help!

P.S. I have tried to change all objects to arrays, this is not changing the situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

Adding `ARRAY_A` forces `get_results()` to return an associative array.